# How to call a persistent worker from repository rule?

Tags: bazel

I need to write a Bazel repository rule which downloads mysql binaries according to some logic which exists in an existing library (which does other things as well).

I'm deliberating the option of starting a persistent jvm worker which will host this library and ask it to just download the archive somewhere and spare me the code duplication.

My questions are:
1. What do I need to do to get up and running with persistent workers? Didn't find a tutorial.
2. What is the correct (bazel wise) location I can tell the worker to download the archive to?

Please feel free to tell me you think I'm making a horrible mistake by delegating this to a worker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot talked to persistent worker from a repository rule easily, but I don't think it is what you want.

You probably want to run your command to download the artifact in the repository_rule then start a persistent worker later in a build rule. The repository rule is not supposed to be executed often so saving on startup time on a repository rule is probably not going to help.